# How to require an IIS site to wait for a Service?

Tags: django, iis, iis-7.5, celery

I have a site hosted through IIS (7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2). The site itself is based on Django (Python), and uses Celery for asynchronous task processing. Celery needs several things to start prior to task processing (celeryd, celerycam, celerybeat), and I have created a Service that starts those. It's set to start Automatically in the Services control panel.

What I'm finding is that after a server restart (auto-update, etc.), my Celery Service is either not starting or there is something wrong with the timing and they are not available to my site that depends on it. Since the site is basically useless without these working, I need to find a way to make sure they are running before the site becomes available.

I'd like to avoid making all of IIS dependent on this Service; just the one site in question (I have a couple of other sites hosted through there on different ports that do not require the Service).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in my opinion is to change your application and make it fail softly when it can't connect to the Celery service. I.e. present an informative error message to the user and give it the option to retry.

It's bad design to make it dependent on the starting order of services. What if the Celery service fails for any reason? Same goes for database connections / queries by the way. Your code should always handle failures/errors gracefully.